# Unity 5.2 compile error "Assertion ... not met"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am relatively new to Unity (about 3 months) and just upgraded to 5.2 and have been using it with Visual Studio for a couple weeks now without issue. Today I am getting this error:

```
* Assertion at ..\mono\metadata\class.c:1423, condition `*sig == 0x06' not met
```

In Visual Studio, it compiles just fine. I have tried "Clean Solution", "Rebuild Solution", and "Build Solution" in Visual Studio and it always comes back as "Build Succeeded". But when I switch back to Unity I get this Assertion problem and it tells me to fix compile errors.

I tried exiting everything and rebooting. No luck. Does anyone know what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Well a new version of Unity was released 5.2.1f1 and when I installed it the problem went away. I am not sure if uninstalling and re-installing the old version would have fixed the problem.